# function based view failed on CSRF verification in Django 1.11.5

Tags: django, csrf-token

I am learning Django by creating a blog site. But when tried to use function based view to create a post got CSRF verification failed.

Using `csrf_exempt` decorator I could create post without error. But for security need to use CSRF protection, could anybody help with a solution please?

```
Django=1.11.5
Python=3.6.8
```

views.py

```
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = request.user
            new_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render_to_response('create.html',{ 'form': form })
```

create.html

```
<h2>Create your post here.</h2>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" value="CREATE">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `render_to_response`. Use `render` which runs context processors such as the one that inserts the csrf token.

```
return render (request, 'create.html',{ 'form': form })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` in `MIDDLEWARE` section add this:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

Answer (score 0):

By replacing render_to_response with render clears this CSRF verification failed. But dont know how does it work? Anybody explain please what is going on?